# Return data when not all values in column are equal

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a simple table which looks like this:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | id | name     | count |
|------------|----|----------|-------|
| 2020-10-31 | 1  | price    | 90    |
| 2020-10-31 | 1  | restrict | 90    |
| 2020-10-31 | 1  | checkin  | 90    |
| 2020-10-31 | 2  | price    | 322   |
| 2020-10-31 | 2  | restrict | 322   |
| 2020-10-31 | 2  | checkin  | 311   |
...
```

How can I construct a query that will return the `id`s that *do not* have the same count for each `name`? So using the above data, `id` 2 would be returned as not all `name` counts are equal.

It would be great if it's possible without hardcoding each name individually as there are a lot in the real dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method is aggregation:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having min(count) <> max(count);
```

If you want to be sure there are three rows, then add `and count(*) = 3`.

Comment: Actually, I think you should do `!=` here but a minor change anyway. With `=`, all rows with the same count will be returned instead of instead of those where the count differs.